# Puzzled about for loops in C

Tags: c, loops, sorting, recursion, insertion-sort

Just to be clear, I understand how for loops work. However, the different syntax causes me problems... Let me give you an example:

I was looking up a recursive sorting algorithm (insertion sort).  The code went like this:

```
void insertion_recursive(int array[],int size){
int i;

if (size<=1) return;

insertion_recursive(array,size-1);

for(i=size-1;i;i--)
   if(array[i]<array[i-1])
       swap(&array[i],&array[i-1]);
   else
       break;
}
```

I understand how the code works, but the condition for the loop is confusing me:

```
for(i=size-1 ; i ; i--)
```

What does it mean?  Just leaving 'i' without specifying a condition?

Comment: But it *does* have a condition! Just like `if (i)...` does.

Comment: `0` is "false", any other value is "true".

Comment: _I understand how for loops work_ - If you did you would not ask the question. When `i` is zero it is false otherwise it is true

Comment: @EdHeal His question does not deal with loops directly... it's more on the semantics of how `i` itself (without any explicit condition) is interpreted as a condition.

Comment: Please tell why it is indirect when `i` is in the `for` statement

Comment: `if (i)` means `if (i != 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression represents a single data item--usually a number. The expression may consist of a single entity, such as a `constant` or `variable`, or it may consist of some combination of such entities, interconnected by one or more operators. Expressions can also represent logical conditions which are either `true` or `false`. However, in C, the conditions `true` and `false` are represented by the non-zero integer values and zero integer value, respectively. Several simple expressions are given below:

```
a + b
x = y
t = u + v
x <= y
++j
```

In your example, `i` is an expression whose value is expression's `l-value` which is in this case, it is the value of variable `i`.
The expression will evaluate to `true` for non-zero `i` values and `false` if value of `i` is zero.

So, `for(i=(size-1); i ; i--)` is equivalent to `for(i=(size-1); i != 0; i--)`.

Comment: I see, condition evaluates to true for ANY non-zero value... I was not aware of that.  So this should also work: for(i=size-1 ; i>0 ; i--)

Answer (score 2):

In C when trying to evaluate a condition, everything that is 0 is false, and everything else is true.

Even pointers are treated the same way. The constant NULL is actually defined as 0. In C++11 we finally have the null_ptr for type safety.

In C there is no bool type, and in C++ if you cast true to integer you get 1, and false casts to 0.

Answer (score 0):

`i` by itself is converted to a boolean, similar to `if (i) {...}` or `if (! i) {...}`; integers are considered `true` when nonzero and `false` when zero.

So, `for(i=size-1 ; i ; i--)` is equivalent to `for(i=size-1 ; i != 0; i--)`.

Comment: Does C convert things to boolean?

Comment: It was a rhetorical question

Comment: `i` by itself is NOT converted to boolean.